Matlab LDPC Decoder: Normal-Min-Sum
I am trying to implement the Min-Sum Decoder for LDPC in Matlab. To check if I do it correctly, I am comparing the output with the min-sum decoder of Matlab.
For Matlab's functions I set the normalization factor to 1. The parity check matrix is the same for both implementations.
For some reason the soft-output of my function compared to the soft-output of Matlab's function is different. I am not sure what is going wrong, I already checked by hand what it could be.
I follow the equations on Matlab's website for the implementation. What I do at the Check node is, I take the first min and the second minimum absolute value of the non-zero entries of a row. Then for that row, put everything to first minimum value, except where it is the minimum value, there I put it to the second minimum value. This repeated for each row separately.
Matlab's function finds less errors than my own implementation.
function bits_hat = ldpc_bp_function_ms(L, H, nb_v_nodes, nb_c_nodes, max_iter) 

% 1) Initial LLRs from VNs to CNs
M = H .* L';
L_int = L;

for idx_iter_llr = 1:1:max_iter             
                % 2) LLRs from CNs to VNs
                A_2 = zeros(nb_c_nodes, nb_v_nodes);

                % Magnitude
                for i = 1:nb_c_nodes
                    h_tmp = logical(H(i, :));
                    m_tmp = abs(M(i, h_tmp)); % Normalization factor
                    [sorted, idx] = sort(m_tmp);
                    m_tmp(m_tmp ~= sorted(1)) = sorted(1);
                    m_tmp(idx(1)) = sorted(2);
                    A_2(i, h_tmp) = m_tmp;
                end

                % Sign
                S_tmp = prod(sign(M + ~H), 2) ./ sign(M + ~H) .* H;

                E = S_tmp .* A_2;

                % Update total LLRs
                E_tmp = sum(E, 1)';
                L = L_int + E_tmp;
                
                % Check if a correct codeword is found 
                bits_hat = L < 0;
                if(~any(mod(double(H) * double(bits_hat), 2)))
                    break;
                end

                % 3) LLRs from VNs to CNs
                M = H .* L' - E;  

end   
end

where
H = logical([1 0 0 1 0 1 1; ...
             0 1 0 1 1 1 0; ...
             0 0 1 0 1 1 1]);

Could someone help me out here? I have tried everything at this point and the results don't match :/
